# IllegalFormatConversionException in rest api service spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to write tests for my service, and some of them are not passing with desription Unexpected exception type thrown, expected: <com.bestteam.urlshorter.exception.ItemNotFoundException> but was: <java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException>

```
    @Test
    public void testGetWhenLinkNotFoundThenThrowException() {
        assertThrows(ItemNotFoundException.class, () -> {
            linkService.get("shortLink");
        });
        verify(linkRepository, times(0)).save(link);
    }
```

and here is this get method

```
  public LinkDto get(String shortLink) {
    Link linkEntity = linkRepository.findById(shortLink).orElseThrow(() -> new ItemNotFoundException(Link.class, shortLink));
    linkEntity.setOpenCount(
      linkEntity.getOpenCount() + 1
    );

    linkRepository.save(linkEntity);
    return linkMapper.toDto(linkEntity);
  }
```

linkMapper is a custom mapper

```
  public LinkDto toDto(Link link) {
    if (link == null) {
      return null;
    }

    LinkDto linkDto = new LinkDto();
    linkDto.setLink(link.getLink());
    linkDto.setShortLink(link.getShortLink());
    linkDto.setOpenCount(link.getOpenCount());
    linkDto.setIsActive(link.getIsActive());
    linkDto.setCreationDateTime(link.getCreationDateTime());
    linkDto.setExpirationDateTime(link.getExpirationDateTime());

    if (link.getUser() != null) {
      linkDto.setUserId(link.getUser().getId());
    }

    return linkDto;
  }
```

The ItemNotFoundException

```
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ItemNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
  public static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Entity not found";

  public ItemNotFoundException() {
    super(DEFAULT_MESSAGE);
  }

  public ItemNotFoundException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }

  public ItemNotFoundException(Class<?> entityClass, Long id) {
    super(String.format("%s: {%s, id=%d}", DEFAULT_MESSAGE, entityClass.getSimpleName(), id));
  }

  public ItemNotFoundException(Class<?> entityClass, String id) {
    super(String.format("%s: {%s, id=%d}", DEFAULT_MESSAGE, entityClass.getSimpleName(), id));
  }
}
```

I tried to create global exception handler using AdviceController, but it did not help

Comment: Can you provide the code of the `com.bestteam.urlshorter.exception.ItemNotFoundException` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in one of the constructors of the `ItemNotFoundException` class:

```java
public ItemNotFoundException(Class<?> entityClass, String id) {
    super(String.format("%s: {%s, id=%d}", DEFAULT_MESSAGE, entityClass.getSimpleName(), id));
}
```

Instead of `%d` you should use `%s`.

Comment: ...because `%d` means format a number here, but `id` is a String, so you must use `%s`